# jquery bootstrap in angular2 selecting carousel image index

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Trying to replicate this simple jquery snippet I have from my old project into angular2. Basically selecting a carousel image index `onclick="" or (click)=""`.

In jQuery its simple as the code below, however when I do the same in angular2 I get `.carousel()` is not a function. I've imported jQuery and bootstrap but the snippet below doesn't seems want to work.

```
// this works on plain jquery
selectImage = function() {
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(2)
}
```

in my angular2 its pretty similar:--

```
import { carousel } from 'bootstrap';
import $ from "jquery";
declare var carousel: any;

// doesn't work shows the error below
selectImage() {
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(2);
}
```

Trying to select image from this div

```
<button (click)="selectImage()"> Select image (2)</button>

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
            <img src="./assets/imgs/4d4853533136_01-lg.jpg"></div>

        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
            <img src="./assets/imgs/4d4853533136_03.jpg"></div>

        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
            <img src="./assets/imgs/4d4853533136_02.jpg"></div>

        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
            <img src="./assets/imgs/4d4853533136_04.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error message: `ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_jquery___default(...)(...).carousel is not a function`

Question is how can I do the same function as my jQuery snippet in angular2?

Bootstrap select specified image number [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_number&stacked=h)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex"` as below. Set "activeSlideIndex" in your click event Or any other event as per requirement

```
<carousel [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides" [(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex">
 <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
     <img [src]="slide.image">

     <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
       <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
     </div>
   </slide>
</carousel>
```

Comment: I'm not using ng-bootstrap which I think you used in your example? Just working on a static carousel. I've added a button in my question, what Im trying to achieve is similar to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_number&stacked=h